# Rounding numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am making a function for finding the approximate value of the second derivative (using the forward difference formula) of $sin(x)$ in $x=\frac {\pi}{3}$ with step $h=10^{-n}$ for $n=1, 2, 3, 4, 5$

The problem is that MATLAB rounds all the results by 4 positions after the decimal which makes all approximations equal. How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

> function [ D2h ] = Forward( n )
> D2h=zeros(n,1); 
> x=pi;
> for i=1:n 
>       h=10^-i;
>       D2h(i,1)=(sin(x+2*h)-2*sin(x+h)+sin(x))/h^2;
>  end

Comment: When I did it [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sin+%28.01%2Bpi%2F3%29-2*sin%28pi%2F3%29%2Bsin%28-.01%2Bpi%2F3%29%29%2F.0001) I get $-0.8653$ for a step of $0.1$ and $-0.8660$ for $0.01$, which differ in the third decimal.  You are right they are very close.  I can't help with the Matlab question.

Comment: I'd try writing after the title of the function "format long;".

Comment: yes, "format long" works, and I also found a function for rounding numbers. For those who are curious [click here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090120084849AAUTg3Z)

Answer (score 2):

Something that many people run into is that by default, matlab only displays 4 decimals. Of course, the precision is not lost, it is just not shown.

If you try `help format` you can find ways to change this behavior.

Some interesting options:

```
format short % Default setting, 4 decimals
format long % Many decimals
format longG % Many decimals if available, won't show trailing zeros
```